# Issue on Grouping the columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `v_leaveallocation_ms` which contains the common columns such as `I_EmpID` and `I_EmpName` and 2 entries with `I_EarnLeave` and `I_FromDate`.

Now I want to get the 2 rows into single row by getting the last entry of I_Fromdate to get I_EarnLeave.

```
select distinct I_empid, I_empname, I_Earnleave, max(I_FromDate) 
from v_leaveallocation_ms 
where i_departmentid = 2
group by I_empid, I_empname, I_Earnleave
```

I got the duplicate entries. Please suggest me.[image]

Comment: show your sql query results

Comment: There are no duplicates because the value for `i_earnleave` is different. Which of the two values for Lawrence do you want returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT l.I_empid, l.I_empname, l.I_Earnleave, l.I_FromDate
  FROM 
(
    SELECT I_empid, MAX(I_FromDate) I_FromDate
      FROM v_leaveallocation_ms
     WHERE i_departmentid = 2 
     GROUP BY I_empid     
) q JOIN v_leaveallocation_ms l
    ON q.I_empid = l.I_empid
   AND q.I_FromDate = l.I_FromDate
```

In the subquery you grab `MAX(I_FromDate)` per `I_empid` and then you join back to your table to get other columns from corresponding rows.

The second approach is to use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function

```
SELECT I_empid, I_empname, I_Earnleave, I_FromDate
  FROM
(
  SELECT I_empid, I_empname, I_Earnleave, I_FromDate,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I_empid ORDER BY I_FromDate DESC) rnum
    FROM v_leaveallocation_ms
   WHERE i_departmentid = 2
) q
 WHERE rnum = 1
```

Output:

```
| I_EMPID |     I_EMPNAME | I_EARNLEAVE |                       I_FROMDATE |
|---------|---------------|-------------|----------------------------------|
|      21 |      Lawrence |          24 | September, 16 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|      28 | N.R.Santharam |          12 |  November, 11 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c836c/3)** demo (*for both queries*)

Comment: That would still return lawrence twice as both rows have the same `i_fromdate`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I believe it wont because OP showed `MAX(I_FromDate)` not `I_FromDate`. He posted the result of his query not simple select from the actual table.

Comment: Ah, right (but still if there *were* two rows with the same max value, both would be returned).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I understand that, but then we can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the only one row. From business point of view duplicate rows with same date make no sense that's why I even didn't suggest the second option

Answer (score 1):

You do not have duplicates in the posted result. The two rows for Lawrence have a different `i_earnleave`. You need to pick one of them. If you want the higher want, remove that column from the `group by` and apply e.g. a `max()` on it.

```
select I_empid, I_empname, max(I_Earnleave), max(trunc(I_FromDate)) 
from v_leaveallocation_ms 
where i_departmentid = 2
group by I_empid, I_empname;
```

If you need all columns that *belong* e.g. to the latest `i_fromdate` you can use a window function:

```
select i_empid, i_empname, i_earnleave, i_fromdate
from (
   select i_empid, i_empname, i_earnleave, i_fromdate,
          row_number() over (partition by i_empid order by i_fromdate desc) as rn
   from v_leaveallocation_ms
   where i_departmentid = 2
) t
where rn = 1;
```

If you want rows with the same `i_fromdate` returned twice, you can replace `row_number()` with `dense_rank()`